Reading ascii data with iText fails
Trying to read ascii data from simple pdf file in C# .NET 8 using iText7
StringBuilder processed = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages(); ++i)
    {
         var page = pdfDocument.GetPage(i);
         string text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page, strategy);
         processed.Append(text);
    }

returns garbled text
����������\n�������������������������\n
Text can copied from PDF in Adobe Acrobat PDF viewer.
PDF is in
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/e21c2093f9a732287383fc5ca97104cd20240414124039/b3ad1e
How to read text from this PDF ?
Can iText configured or some other PDF reading librady used ?
This is already asked in
Reading text from pdf with iText7 + C#, text not recognized
but not solved.

PDF is not text.  It is a proprietary binary file.  Some data may look like ordinary text, but there are control characters (binary characters) that surround the text.

The PDF file has a bad font table and a secondary problem of overset text (overlapping).
There are 2 ways to deal with a file like this (that looks good in Acrobat) but mis behaves in other applications and both are reprint.
I tried several ways and thus found Acrobat Print to GhostScript Postscript was best since PDF to PDF simply carried the errors over. Then convert the Postscript in GhostScript back to PDF.
You could use the old command line method of run Poppler/Xpdf PDFtoPS or GhostScript convert to PS then GhostScript PS back to PDF. But it will still have the overset text.
Once the fonts are resolved you could try again with iTeXt or I simply ran poppler PDFtoTeXT so as to remove the overset. Link to latest current 64bit version. For Windows 32 bit users and others you may  need to use Xpdf command line tools: currently v4.05 (https://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html).  So for example with poppler and target page 1.
NOTE with this particular file, Poppler performed noticeably better than Xpdf. However your results  may vary depending on language, input, platform and settings!
pdftotext -layout -nopgbrk -enc UTF-8   -fixed 3.1 "in-fixed.pdf"  "out.txt"

Result
                                                                                             Tarnija:                                                                        Rolling OÜ
                                                                                             Registrikood / KMKR nr.:                                        12571469 /     EE101695107
                                                                                             Aadress:                                                       Betooni tn 1, Tallinn, 11415
                                                                                             Kaupade väljastamiskoht:                                       Betooni tn 1, Tallinn, 11415
                                                                                             Panga nimetus:                                                    SEB PANK AS, EEUHEE2X

          Arve:             2403793            EST                      09.04.2024
                                                                                             Panga konto:                                                       EE131010220225504229
                                                                                             Kontaktinformatsioon:                                Telefon: 6 280 808; Faks: 6 280 809
          Maksekuupäev:                                                 09.05.2024           Teie kontaktisik:                                                          Angelina Burtseva

          Vedaja:                                                       ROLLING OÜ           Saaja:                                                             DGM SHIPPING, AS
          Registreerimisnumber:                                              12571469
          Sõiduki juhi eesnimi, perekonnanimi:                                               Kliendi number                                                                         71771
          Sõiduki registreerimisnumber:                                                      Registrikood / KMKR nr.:                                         10061617 / EE100412077
          Tehingu kirjeldus:                                        kaupade tarnimine        Aadress:                                                   A. Puškini tn 9-6, Narva, 20309
          Piirkond:                                             NEW - EAST TALLINN           Kaupade kättesaamiskoht:                       Nurmevälja tn 1 Maardu Harjumaa 74114
                                                                                             Panga nimetus:
                                                                                             Panga konto:
          Makseviis:                                                            30 days      Maksja:                                                                  DGM SHIPPING, AS

          Kommentaar:
          Kaubad on tarnija omand seni, kuni nende eest on täielikult tasutud

                                                                                                                                       Kogus/           Hind                 Summa
              Artikkel             Nimetus                                                                                                                          %
                                                                                                                                         Ühik        ilma KM                 ilma KM

                                   Saateleht 2405326 [STOCK] (EAST)
                                   Nurmevälja tn 1 Maardu Harjumaa 74114
           17-02-0206              Paberrätik Tork Basic M2, 280 m, 1 kiht, valge 6 rulli, 140002                                           1 IEPAK        30.05      4.1            28.82
           17-26-0269              Tänavahari Saima Broom, 25 x 120 cm, must/punane                                                         1 GAB           9.16      4.9             8.71
           08-05-0005              Käärid Office Point, 15.5 cm, Soft-Grip                                                                  1 TÜKK          1.35     17.5             1.11
           04-07-0238              Ilmastikukindlad kleebisetiketid Herma 99.1 x 93.1 mm, 25 lehte, valged, väga tugeva kinnitusega         1 IEPAK        30.85     15.7            26.01
           17-01-0128              Tualettpaber Jumbo Clean, 12 rulli, 2 kihti, valge                                                       1 IEPAK        23.80      4.5            22.73
                                   Saateleht 2404987 [STOCK] (EAST),DMM, Viidud, 03.04.2024, 13:46
                                   Nurmevälja tn 1 Maardu Harjumaa 74114
           04-02-0225              Märkmepaber Forofis, 51x76mm,100p., kollane                                                              3 GAB           0.46     20.4             1.10
...
continued down to
...
           05-01-0010              Ümbrikud iseliimuva kleepribaga, C5, 25 tk. Valge                                                        2 PK            1.37     17.0             2.27
           05-01-0008              Ümbrikud iseliimuva kleepribaga, C6, 25 tk. Valge                                                        4 PK            0.87     17.1             2.88
           01-05-0197              Sissetõmmatav geelist tindipliiats ErichKrause Smart-Gel, 0,5 mm, tindi värv: sinine                    12GAB            0.60     18.4             5.88


In comments the discussion showed only a small section of page 1 and 4 was desired, and that can be done direct on the poor quality source via poppler PDFtoText.
For example to extract a line via a word or two or an area we can use,
pdftotext -f 1 -l 1 -layout -enc UTF-8 "rolling garbage Arve_24037931.pdf" - 2>nul |Findstr "Rolling EST KMKR Makseku" >temp.txt

So far that gives from page 1 - Note the query cannot include UTF accents but result can!
                                                                           Tarnija:                                                             Rolling OÜ
                                                                           Registrikood / KMKR nr.:                                12571469 / EE101695107
Arve:          2403793 EST                            09.04.2024
Maksekuupäev:                                         09.05.2024           Teie kontaktisik:                                                Angelina Burtseva
Sõiduki registreerimisnumber:                                              Registrikood / KMKR nr.:                             10061617 / EE100412077


Similar we can add data from bottom of page 4
pdftotext -f 4 -l 4 -layout -enc UTF-8 "rolling garbage Arve_24037931.pdf" - 2>nul |Findstr "Summa 22% Kokku" >>temp.txt

so now we have core data.
                                                                           Tarnija:                                                             Rolling OÜ
                                                                           Registrikood / KMKR nr.:                                12571469 / EE101695107
Arve:          2403793 EST                            09.04.2024
Maksekuupäev:                                         09.05.2024           Teie kontaktisik:                                                Angelina Burtseva
Sõiduki registreerimisnumber:                                              Registrikood / KMKR nr.:                             10061617 / EE100412077
                                                                                                       Kogus/          Hind              Summa
                                                                                           Summa ilma käibemaksutaEUR                        370.37
                                                                                       *2403793r*                         22%EUR                  81.48
                                                                                                                        KokkuEUR             451.85


Text is extracted in MVC Controller which processes lot of pdf files daily.  Should ghostscript executed two times from controller to convert it to ps and then ps back to pdf in this case? pdf file is opened in iText. Maybe it is possible to fix font table so that running ghostscript is not requred? Only invoice number, customer name, total sum and vat are extracted from text. Overlapping text occurs in middle of invoice and this part of invoice is not used for processing. Or maybe there is some .net package which can used to fix pdf to avoid running external application in server?

Error is in single file only. Same customer may send new pdf in future and it has probably the same issue. I need Arve: 2403793, ROLLING OÜ, 12571469 and dates from first page and sum 370.37 and VAT 81.48 from last page. Maybe there is some other software which can extract text from this pdf file like acrobat copy does or can this text extracted from ps or other file? ASP.NET application runs in windows and in Linux. It would be better to avoid running external applications from controller in server.

Tried pdftotext from https://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html. It still does not open original pdf file. Is ghostscript still required to make this pdf file extractable?
